# ZF2 inserting data to Db

Tags: zend-framework2

During saving I recive an error:

> values() expects an array of values or Zend\Db\Sql\Select instance

I think error comes from:

```
$this->tableGateway->insert($procedure);
```

I don't understand what is wrong.

This is my process function:

```
public function processAction()
    {
         if (!$this->request->isPost()){
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute(null, array('controller'=>'test', 'action'=>'index'));
        }

        $post = $this->request->getPost();
        $form = new TestForm();
        $inputFilter = new \Postepowania\Form\TestFilter();
        $form->setInputFilter($inputFilter);
        $form->setData($post);

        if (!$form->isValid()){
            $model = new ViewModel(
                array(
                    'error' => true,
                    'form' =>$form,
                )
            );            
            $model->setTemplate('postepowania/test/index');
            return $model;
        }

        $this->createTest($form->getData());    
        //return $this->redirect()->toRoute(null,array('controller' => 'test','action' => 'confirm',));
    }
```

and createTest function:

```
 public function createTest(array $data){

        $testTable = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('TestTable');
        $test = new Test();
        $test->exchangeArray($data);

        $testTable->save($test);

        return true;
    }
```

Save function is very simple:

```
public function save(Test $procedure)
    {
        $id = (int)$procedure->id;
        if($id == 0)
        {
            $this->tableGateway->insert($procedure);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you print_r the expression in question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->tableGateway->insert()
```

From looking at the [source](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/TableGateway/AbstractTableGateway.php#L256), `insert()` requires an array to be passed into it, not an object. I suggest converting your object to an array before passing it in.

Comment: +1 I would change the `createTest()` method. Instead of  `$testTable->save($test);` use `$testTable->save($data);` and then `return $test;`.